# A binding in intranet

Tags: wcf

I have to choose a binding in intranet area without certificates.
I have 2 wcf services on different computers.
Firstly I've chosen net.tcp binding. net.tcp + windows authentication - works fine!
But later I knew that some clients may don't have AD, so I decided to use basicHttpBinding.
What bindings without certificates can I use in intranet where may or may not be AD?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can have two endpoints. One for clients that do have AD available and another using username/password (or whatever authentication mechanism you want to use) for clients without AD. The service implementation could be identical.